# How to add a song to a playlist in android?

Tags: android

I have tried this but it isn't working

```
uri=android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",id);
ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.IS_MUSIC, 1);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.TITLE,body);
Log.v("song",body);
Log.v("id",""+ID);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,ID);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAYLIST_ID, id);
Log.v("play",""+id);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER,2);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID, 7);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER,"play_order");

Uri x=resolver.insert(uri, values);  
if(x==null)
{
    Log.v("success","unsuccess");
}
else
{
    Log.v("success","success");
}
```

I have kept play_order to because the highest vale is 1 for the songs already existing in the playlist . Similarly I have put `ID=7` .

Comment: you found your ans ?? if yes can u plz share it.